# AES 256 bit encryption with 256 block size in iOS

Tags: ios, encryption, aes

Does iOs support AES 256 bit encryption with 256 block size and CBC Mode ? Is there any library available ?

Comment: Yes, of course it supports. Help yourself, please do some research before posting a question. I recommend you to start with `CommonCrypto` framework available in iOS.

Comment: It's not called AES anymore. AES is only specified for 128-bit block size. Only Rijndael is specified for 192 and 256-bit block sizes additionally. Also, recommendation requests are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: I have done research. there is no 256 block size option available in CommonCrypto.

Comment: As @ArtjomB. notes, there is no such thing as AES with a block size of 256-bits. The algorithm used by AES, Rijndael, supports it, but in that configuration it isn't "AES" any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common Crypto only supports AES with a block size of 128-bits.

For a 256-bit block size you need to use Rijndael from a 3rd party implementation.

"For AES, NIST selected three members of the Rijndael family, each with a block size of 128 bits, but three different key lengths: 128, 192 and 256 bits." (from WikiPedia)

Common Crypto supports the three AES key sizes.

Comment: can you please suggest any Rijndael 3rd party code in ios